# Red chilli plant, do I have a problem and how do I fix?

Tags: plant-health, chili

[image]

My chillies were growing fine but all of a sudden have started to develop this yellowing (soft/hollow to touch) near the tips of some of my chillies, would anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening and if it's a problem how would I go about fixing it please?

[image]

So after cutting open this is what the yellowing chilli loss like

Comment: Remove the chilies, you will not eat them anyway. But so, you can look better at the fruits and look if if see something strange. How did you water the chilies? (peppers have frequently such problems, but never seen in chilli, so or you are doing watering very wrong, or I assume there is an other cause).